# How can I save the packet list exactly as Wireshark is displaying it as a JSON?

Tags: json, lua, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I'm using company-provided Wireshark dissectors for 3 proprietary network protocols used by that company.

I want to further analyse the packet capture data, so I need Wireshark to transform it into a common format like JSON. Wireshark knows how to interpret the data using the dissectors and I can access all the fields in the Wireshark GUI.

`tshark -r file.pcapng -V -Tjson > file.json` almost does what I want. But for some reason, it substitutes a lot of, but not all the "field-name":"value"-pairs with "_ws.lua.text":"".
The same thing happens if I export the packet dissection to JSON in the GUI. In Wireshark everything looks fine, but the JSON file doesn't.

So I know Wireshark has the data I want. How can I make Wireshark save the packet list, exactly as it displays it with all fields expanded, as a JSON file?

Possibly helpful theory of mine:
I noticed that in the .lua dissector file, most of the field names that are substituted are defined like this:

```
local table = {
   [0] = {
        [1] = {decription="field name 1"}
        [2] = {description="field name 2"}
         }}
```

and referenced as `table[0][2].description`
Maybe "_ws.lua.text" is just a stub for any reference that is returned instead of a value? But Wireshark can access the values, so why doesn't it use them when converting the data to JSON?

Comment: Maybe you can work with this output?  `tshark -r json.pcap -Y json -O json`

Comment: No, there is no json data in the packets. I want to save the packet data as json so I can use them with other software.